# Login using two Dictionary

Tags: python

```
def login():

while True: 
    username = input("Please enter your username or x to quit: ")
    if username.casefold() == "x":
        break
    else:
        password = input("\nPlease enter your password: ")

    if username =="" or password =="":
        print("You cannot leave this blank,Please try again.")


    else:
        if len(username)>0 and len(password)>0: 
            for i in memberDict:
                if username == i and password == memberDict[i]:
                    print(f"Login successful, Welcome Member, {memberDict[i]}")
                    statuslist.append(0)
                    break
                else:
                    for i in adminDict:
                        if username == i and password == adminDict[i]:
                            print(f"Login successful, Welcome Admin, {adminDict[i]}")
                            statuslist.append(1)
                            break
                        else:
                            print("Login failed, There is no registered customers. Please try again.")
```

I am trying to login via 2 different dictionaries. Dictionary works fine, just having issues having to read both of them and separate them as admin users or members

im trying to append 0 as member, 1 as admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if content of memberDict and adminDict do not duplicate, then you do need to go through all users in both dict to check if user exist, just use a found variable so it reduce time complexity from O(member) * O(admin) to O(member) + O(admin)

```
def login():
    while True: 
        username = input("Please enter your username or x to quit: ")
        if username.casefold() == "x":
            break
        else:
            password = input("\nPlease enter your password: ")

        if username =="" or password =="":
            print("You cannot leave this blank,Please try again.")


        else:
            if len(username)>0 and len(password)>0: 
                found = False
                for i in memberDict:
                    if username == i and password == memberDict[i]:
                        print(f"Login successful, Welcome Member, {memberDict[i]}")
                        statuslist.append(0)
                        found = True
                        break
                for i in adminDict:
                    if username == i and password == adminDict[i]:
                        print(f"Login successful, Welcome Admin, {adminDict[i]}")
                        statuslist.append(1)
                        found = True
                        break
                if not found:
                    print("Login failed, There is no registered customers. Please try again.")
```

Comment: I'm not too sure why, but it keeps promting me. Are you a member here? Member are entitled to 10 Percent discount. If you are press L, Press R to register , Press G to login as guest or X to exit program. despite being successfully checked by dictionary.

Comment: it's alright, I think I got it. You saved my soul, I was stuck at this issue for at least 6hours

Answer (score 0):

The second "admin" loop appears within the member dict loop.

that is you should:

```
for i in memberDict:
    if username == i and password == memberDict[i]:
        print(f"Login successful, Welcome Member, {memberDict[i]}")
        statuslist.append(0)
        login=True
for i in adminDict:
    if username == i and password == adminDict[i]:
        print(f"Login successful, Welcome Admin, {adminDict[i]}")
        statuslist.append(1)
        login=True
if not login:
    print("Login failed, There is no registered customers. Please try again.")
```

But in fact, you should probably not iterate over the dicts.  you can tell if the key `i` is in dict memberDict or adminDict by

```
if i in memberDict:
    if memberDict[i] == password:
       # Display login message
```

and likewise for adminDict

---

edit for clarity:

What I meant to say is that you're trying to locate a `key` and `value` pair if it exists in your dicts.  you do not need to iterate over the dicts (that is, use a `for` loop).  You can find out if a `key` is in a dict (in your case, a username in a `MemberDict` by using `if i in memberDict` -> returns True if the key `i` is in the dict, false otherwise.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for helping me out, i do not understand what you mean by "you should probably not iterate over the dicts. you can tell if the key i is in dict memberDict or adminDict by"   Kinda a newbie here!

Comment: @EhFabian You're right I wasn't clear.

What I meant to say is that you're trying to locate a `key` and `value` pair if it exists in your dicts.  you do not need to iterate over the dicts (that is, use a for loop).  You can find out if a `key` is in a dict (in your case, a username in a `MemberDict` by using `if i in memberDict` -> returns True if the key `i` is in the dict, false otherwise.